# Volume and area with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: volume, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having a lot of trouble solving for these problems. I know I have to Use Lagrange multipliers but I don't know how to apply it. Here is the problem:

[image: problem]

Comment: In the title, when you wrote Laplace (known for the transform), did you mean Lagrange (another European mathematician who lived around 1800)?

Comment: Can you set up the system of equations? Once you have, generally in a 2D problem you can eliminate $\lambda$ by dividing and cross multiplying, reducing the two LM equations into the single equation $f_x g_y = f_y g_x$. Note that it may be handy here to work with $S^2$ instead of $S$.

Comment: yes thank you @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @Ian I'm really not sure how to do the steps

Comment: Can you at least get it set up so that the problem reduces to the algebra?

Comment: @Ian I don't really understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

For a) We have the equation $$3=\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$$. We will use this equation to eliminate one variable in $$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$. From the first equation above we get by squaring
$$\frac{9}{\pi r^2}-r^2=h^2$$ so $$h=\sqrt{\frac{9}{\pi r^2}-r^2}$$ so $$V(r)=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2\sqrt{\frac{9}{\pi r^2}-r^2}$$. Now you can compute the first derivative and determine the optimal $r$.
For b) Since it is $$V=3$$ given, we can eliminate $h$, so we get
$$h=\frac{9}{\pi r^2}$$ so we get
$$S(r)=\pi r\sqrt{r^2+\frac{81}{r^2r^4}}$$

Comment: it says that for a I have to write the expression without the use of r or h, how would I do that? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @Alex.G The answers in all three of those boxes are going to be numbers.

Comment: In (a) you wrote $V(h)$ as a function of $r$, not $h$. Wouldn't it be easier to isolate $r^2$ rather than $h^2$ in the squared surface area equation and substitute that in for $r^2$ in the volume formula for a simple polynomial function?